# Unbound JavsSE 1.7 libraries in Java Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, static-libraries

I am very new to Java and Eclipse. I am working on a java project that uses Jave SE 1.7 . I had Java version 1.6 installed in Mac OS. I have installed now Jave SE 1.7 to run this project, but in the libraries section of the project shows `JavaSE 1.7 (unbound)`. The project does not compile and show lots of error. How can I bind the JavaSE 1.7 library with the project?

Answer (score 3):

After you actually install jdk 7, you need to tell Eclipse about it. Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs.
After that tell your project which JRE to use if the new one is not the default one.

Comment: it shows java SE 6 (MacOSX default). But, I see the list of all the installed libraries in the Execution Environment (Eclipse->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs->Execution Environment) which also include JavaSe 1.7. how do i change the default MacOSX java SE6 to javaSE 1.7?

Comment: Thanks to @RomainHippeau I was able to manually add the JDK 1.7 to Eclipse with the path returned by `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` (wich was `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home` for me). I wonder why Eclipse isn't able to detect it automatically on Mac OS X...

Answer (score 2):

Check these two panels.  Remove the unbounded 1.6 JRE and then configure the newly installed 1.7 JRE.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above answers, You should also confirm that the project is using a Java 1.7 compiler level.
**Right click** on the the project and click **Properties**. Click Java Comiler and Check that the compiler level is also set to Java 1.7.
See the image below[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was also having this problem but for me 1.8 JRE was unbound. The process to solve this is still the same.

1. Go to Eclipse -> Preferences
2. Java -> Installed JREs
3. You will see Java SE 6 already there and checked.
4. To see the other JREs you have installed, click on the "search" button

[image]
5. You will now see the other JREs you have installed, now check mark the JRE you want to use and restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse in Windows:

Select Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs->Add.

[image]

Choose your JRE Type and click Next.

[image]

Select 'Directory...' and find the *jre7* folder usually located under **C:\Program Files\Java\jre**, click Finish.

[image]

Once it's added, select jre7 and click OK.

[image]